# NSIntegers returning <nil> instead of 0

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a picker in my app with rows 0 to 5, and the selection defined thus:

```
@property (assign) NSInteger pickerRowSelected;
```

On startup, I assign `pickerRowSelected` to be -1 so I can be sure the user actually changed something. However, this doesn't work, and I'd like some advice on a better solution.

The first problem I noticed is that if the user selects row 0, this code failed:

```
if (self.pickerRowSelected >= 0) {
```

When I po'ed `[self pickerRowSelected]` in gdb I got `<nil>`. For a lark I did this:

```
if (self.pickerRowSelected == nil || self.pickerRowSelected >= 0) {
```

And that worked, although the compiler complains. But I thought that nil *was* a zero in NSInteger, so can anyone explain why the `if` is failing? Suggestions on the correct way to test this?

Comment: When do you write `self.pickerRowSelected = -1;`?  When do you run that `if` statement?

Comment: To inspect the value, use `p [self pickerRowSelected]`.  Also, why are you using gdb and not lldb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is elsewhere. nil is equal to 0. You're getting nil in GDB because you're using
po xyz
with non-pointer types you need to use
p xyz

Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Ah, I see if I use p [self pickerRowSelected] then I get "0". Duh.